# Adding dynamic eventlistners in VueJS3/Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, custom-data-attribute

Im currently struggling with something where i want to add a data attribute to a component and then based on when NUXT is loaded have a click event bind to all nodes that have this data attribute. Im not using v-on because i want to have this separated from current Vue logic. So example:

component a.vue is tagged with data-element

```
  <a href="/somelink" data-element>link</a>
```

component b.vue also has HTM elements tagged with data-element

```
 <button data-element>link</button>
```

When the app loads i need to then loop through all data-element and bind an eventlistner to them.

I tried the above method and that works to some degree but fails when reactivity sets in and the DOM is updated. I checked mixins (not recommended using VueJS3), used composition API, used a mutation observer that checked the DOM status for changes and based on new elements loaded it ads click events, looked at hooks etc but now im getting confused at what is the best way to proceed. Some solutions work to some extend but feels hacky. Or is there a completely different approach i am missing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why can't you use a Vue event here? Maybe [render functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx) would be a nice way of doing things here if you want to use a lot of tag dynamically. Don't use vanilla eventListeners, it will get messy otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to add global functions to fire whenever there is a click or some element that scrolls into view or an input is blurred or focused. Previously this was achievable with a classic setup (ie. no framework) by just looping through the elements that were tagged with a specific data-attribute, and vanillajs just does the rest. And that is what im trying to achieve here as well.  Im currently checking the render functions and also if maybe a custom directive can do the job.

Comment: You can always apply those keyboard/click listeners to the default layout. Not a lot of difference overall at the end. Depends also on what you want to use them for, maybe reactivity is not needed. Render functions may be overkill overall, if your use case is that simple. As of if something is in the viewport or blurred, this is usually to be done on the component itself or via IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 0):

To be Sure that the DOM has been initialized you need to set your event listeners on "mounted" lifecycle

```
mounted() {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-element]')];
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => { /* your code here. */ })
  })
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to remove them on the "unmounted" lifecycle hook.

Comment: Probably not a good way to go since you will need to handle the removal, it's not reactive etc...

Comment: I think will be no need to remove the event listener, as @user732238 said, the elements which have "data-element" attribute will be in different components, So the "mounted" method will be applied to a high-level component which will not be unmounted.

Comment: Still, why getting out Vue's reactivity system? Also, this question is related to Nuxt and I'm not sure that event listeners are good with SSR in general (memory leaks etc...).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, im revisiting the mounted option again.